# Run an exe with arguments that come from a text file

Tags: c#, wpf, text, process

As the title says I'm trying to run an EXE with parameters/arguments that come from a TXT file (in ressource) I know how to start a program with arguments but not arguments from a TXT.
This is what I have done but seems to don't work !

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat("RustClient.exe"));
        startInfo.Arguments = @"Resources\arguments.txt";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

It starts the program but without the arguments I put in the txt file.

If I want to read them from a TXT is because I want them to be editable. Basically, my program will be an easy way to edit launch options for guys who don't know them

I'm a very very noob at coding it's my first coding project I have to google everything ^^

Comment: What you did now is give the path to the file as an argument. If you want the text in that file as an argument you should first parse the text file (read) and than give the parsed content as argument to your process call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read argument text first from the file then assign it to arguments

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string arg = File.ReadAllText("text file location");
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat("RustClient.exe"));
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Omg it was so fast ! Thank you for your fast reply, but it says FileNotFindExeption

Comment: yeah set the location of file `@"Resources\arguments.txt"` correctly then it will work

Comment: I did something wrong ? http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/41/1476335107-file-not-found.png

Comment: yes your file location refers to a location outside your debug folder, you need to provide a location like `D:\sample.text` as hard coded or place your file inside your debug folder. like create a new folder name `Text` inside `Debug` folder then place `arguments.txt` inside there then you can reffere it as `@Text\arguments.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to read an exe file that uses input.txt as an argument, I've alredy tried multiple solutions from various links including the above one. The same exe file when run through a command window passing input.txt as an argument is giving me the right output, but on visual studio it's not giving me any output. I'm new to this so just help me out. Here's the code:>

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\khannapr\decoder_test\dist\test.exe"; // Replace with the actual path to test.exe
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.Start();

            // Read input from the input.txt file
            string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\khannapr\decoder_test\input.txt"); // Replace with the actual path to input.txt

            // Write input to the process
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
            process.StandardInput.Close();

            // Read output from the process
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've tried to pass the input file as command line argument in debug options of VS, I've also tried to frame my path with {"/","//","","\",any other possible way} the VS version I'm using is 2019

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).